# Пунктуация в деловом письме после фразы "сообщаем следующее"

Tags: пунктуация

Деловое письмо начинается следующим образом: "Организация рассмотрела Ваше заявление об организации бесплатных семинаров и сообщает следующее." Далее начинается новый абзац о результатах рассмотрения заявления. Допустим ли такой вариант в рамках правил пунктуации русского языка? Если недопустимо, то какими правилами русского языка руководствуемся в данном случае? Какие допустимые варианты написания подобных фраз в письме?

Answer (score 2):

У Розенталя есть тема "Знаки препинания в конце предложения и при перерыве речи". Там, в частности,  указывается:

1) Ставится точка

Точка ставится в конце предложения, вводящего в дальнейшее развернутое изложение:

Вот этот рассказ. (Пауст.) [дальше следует рассказ];

Представьте себе СЛЕДУЮЩЕЕ. [дальше — подробное повествование];

Новый станок имеет такое устройство. [дальше — пространное описание].

2) Пример с двоеточием

Пишутся слитно:

1. Наречия, образованные соединением предлогов с наречиями… навряд ли, задаром. <…>
2. Наречия, образованные соединением предлогов в и на с собирательными числительными… натрое, но: по двое, по трое.

http://techwriters.ru/news/biblioteka/rozental.html